# Google App Engine POST 500 Missing Module sklearn.pipeline

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

Run down on the UI: It accepts a string, brings that to the backend (using Flask, named `main.py`), does some ML magic, and returns a JSON back to the frontend.

Running the UI locally works fine, however when deploying it to Google's App Engine I get a status 500. Looking at the logs, I see that I have a `moduleError: No module named sklearn.pipeline` Thing is, I don't use this, nor is this in my `requirements.txt` Here's the traceback object from the Logs Viewer:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/vmagent/app/main.py", line 61, in run_pipeline
    text_clf = pickle.load(handle)
ImportError: No module named sklearn.pipeline


{
    insertId: "1mjwzxmecegyg"
    labels: {
        appengine.googleapis.com / instance_name: "aef-default-20171019t101524-k2kk"
        compute.googleapis.com / resource_id: "7187158353674854010"
        compute.googleapis.com / resource_name: "31d3314567f8"
        compute.googleapis.com / zone: "us-central1-b"
    }
    logName: "projects/maximal-ascent-183217/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstderr"
    receiveTimestamp: "2017-10-19T17:37:19.968312342Z"
    resource: {
        labels: {
            module_id: "default"
            project_id: "maximal-ascent-183217"
            version_id: "20171019t101524"
        }
        type: "gae_app"
    }
    textPayload: "Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
    line 1982,
    in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
    File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
    line 1614,
    in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
    line 1517,
    in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
    line 1612,
    in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
    File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
    line 1598,
    in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint]( ** req.view_args)
    File "/home/vmagent/app/main.py",
    line 61,
    in run_pipeline
    text_clf = pickle.load(handle)
    ImportError: No module named sklearn.pipeline "  
    timestamp: "2017-10-19T17:37:18Z"
}
```

Confused on what to do at this point: Should I install the module and use it in my main.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post the solution I found:

Although my main.py doesn't require scipy or sklearn, I needed both those modules in the requirements.txt for one of the pickle files. Gotta make sure your requirements.txt is consistent when deploying to App Engine.